# Throttling consumption of Servicebus messages with azure functions

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus, throttling

We have built several solutions for clients based on azure functions and servicebus to move data between systems. Each solution hosts many (100+) individual functions triggering on individual topics from many different systems.
Although some solutions are older, the majority are .net 8 isolated functions and a solution should be based on that.
These functions are using the Worker.Extensions.Servicebus bindings to trigger off of the queues.

Lately we have experienced issues with a system that is unable to process the amount of data and we therefor need to throttle requests.

How do I throttle messages read of azures queues while still using azure functions?

In other words, how do i make sure only a certain number of messages are processed at a time from select queues?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I appreciate the edit, but you've now made your question about opinions and it's likely to get closed based on that. You really should post your code that you're using and ask us how to throttle with that specific code. That's answerable. Right now this question isn't answerable.

Comment: I appreciate and understand your comment, but this isn't a specific code question. I'll try to add to the question.